# Ads not displaying using real ad unit id instead of test ad unit id

Tags: android, admob

In my application, I have integrated ads from AdMob. When I use my test unit ID, `ca-

 app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712`, it shows test ads successfully. However, when I use my production ad unit ID, it shows nothing. 
In logcat, I see `ads loading error code 0`. Why are my ads failing to load?

This is the code I am using:

```
 MobileAds.initialize(activity, main_interstial_addunit_id);
    final InterstitialAd interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(activity);
    interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(main_interstial_addunit_id);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                interstitialAd.show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
            super.onAdFailedToLoad(i);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLeftApplication() {
            super.onAdLeftApplication();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {
            super.onAdOpened();
        }
    });
    return interstitialAd;
```

Comment: what is the admob error code you are seeing in logcat?

Comment: Wait for sometime,..It will take time for first time

Comment: i am not getting any error

Comment: how much time it will take i not added payment detaile's  but i just want to know is it working or not instead of using test addunitid

Comment: If ads not showing then some error code should be showing. Like, if error code is 3 (no fill) -> it shows initially because need time to fill ads. It will be ok automatically but if you show other error codes then there might be some other issues .

Comment: yeah  i am getting errorcode 0 what it means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as you are getting error code 0 this means "failed to load ads"

From [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/fBe3YL3ffpo%5B1-25%5D) conversation,

> It could be that you have only recently created a new Ad Unit ID and requesting for live ads. It could take a few hours for ads to start getting served if that is that case. If you are receiving test ads then your implementation is fine. Just wait a few hours and see if you are able to receive live ads then. If not, can send us your Ad Unit ID for us to look into.

So, after some times you will be automatically get ads.

**Important: Ad type of your ad unit id needs to be same of ad type where you set that id**